# wxpython fails to install on macosx 10.7.5, on MacBook early 2007

Tags: macos

Below is the result of entering 'brew install wxpython' on MacBook early 2007 with MacOS X 10.7.5.

---

```
Last login: Mon Aug 14 09:27:25 on console
s@s-3.local:~$ brew install wxpython
Updating Homebrew...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/core).
No changes to formulae.

==> Installing dependencies for wxpython: jpeg, libpng, libtiff, wxmac
==> Installing wxpython dependency: jpeg
==> Downloading http://www.ijg.org/files/jpegsrc.v9b.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> ./configure --disable-silent-rules --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/jpeg/9b
==> make install
üç∫  /usr/local/Cellar/jpeg/9b: 20 files, 764.6KB, built in 34 seconds
==> Installing wxpython dependency: libpng
==> Downloading https://download.sourceforge.net/libpng/libpng-1.6.31.tar.xz
==> Downloading from https://managedway.dl.sourceforge.net/project/libpng/libpng16/1.6.
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> ./configure --disable-silent-rules --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.6.31
==> make
==> make test
==> make install
==> Caveats
This formula is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because macOS already provides this software in versions before Mountain Lion.

If you need to have this software first in your PATH run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/libpng/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile

For compilers to find this software you may need to set:
    LDFLAGS:  -L/usr/local/opt/libpng/lib
    CPPFLAGS: -I/usr/local/opt/libpng/include
For pkg-config to find this software you may need to set:
    PKG_CONFIG_PATH: /usr/local/opt/libpng/lib/pkgconfig

==> Summary
üç∫  /usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.6.31: 26 files, 1.2MB, built in 2 minutes 29 seconds
==> Installing wxpython dependency: libtiff
==> Downloading http://download.osgeo.org/libtiff/tiff-4.0.8.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/s/Library/Caches/Homebrew/libtiff-4.0.8.tar.gz
==> Downloading https://mirrors.ocf.berkeley.edu/debian/pool/main/t/tiff/tiff_4.0.8-4.d
Already downloaded: /Users/s/Library/Caches/Homebrew/libtiff--patch-36c008179ae08d6958cd9fcd75f82c082624bf55e2c4e6ca0e1af59ea4d75d9c.tar.xz
==> Patching
==> Applying patches/01-CVE-2015-7554.patch
patching file tools/tiffsplit.c
==> Applying patches/02-CVE.patch
patching file ChangeLog
patching file libtiff/tif_color.c
==> Applying patches/03-CVE.patch
patching file ChangeLog
patching file libtiff/tif_getimage.c
==> Applying patches/04-CVE-2016-10095_CVE-2017-9147.patch
patching file ChangeLog
patching file libtiff/tif_dir.h
patching file libtiff/tif_dirinfo.c
patching file libtiff/tif_dirread.c
==> Applying patches/05-CVE-2017-9936.patch
patching file ChangeLog
patching file libtiff/tif_jbig.c
==> Applying patches/06-OOM_in_gtTileContig.patch
patching file ChangeLog
patching file libtiff/tif_getimage.c
patching file libtiff/tif_read.c
patching file libtiff/tiffiop.h
==> Applying patches/07-CVE-2017-10688.patch
patching file ChangeLog
patching file libtiff/tif_dirwrite.c
==> Applying patches/08-LZW_compression_regression.patch
patching file ChangeLog
patching file libtiff/tif_lzw.c
==> Applying patches/09-CVE-2017-11335.patch
patching file ChangeLog
patching file tools/tiff2pdf.c
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/libtiff/4.0.8_3 --without-x --with-jpeg-incl
==> make install
üç∫  /usr/local/Cellar/libtiff/4.0.8_3: 245 files, 3.5MB, built in 58 seconds
==> Installing wxpython dependency: wxmac
==> Downloading https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/releases/download/v3.0.3.1/wxWid
==> Downloading from https://github-production-release-asset-2e65be.s3.amazonaws.com/17
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Downloading https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/commit/9a610eadcfe.patch?full_in
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Patching
==> Applying 9a610eadcfe.patch
patching file configure
Hunk #1 succeeded at 19769 (offset -1 lines).
patching file configure.in
patching file docs/changes.txt
Hunk #1 succeeded at 586 with fuzz 2 (offset -9 lines).
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/wxmac/3.0.3.1_1 --enable-clipboard --enable-
==> make install
Last 15 lines from /Users/s/Library/Logs/Homebrew/wxmac/02.make:
Thread model: posix
clang: note: diagnostic msg: PLEASE submit a bug report to http://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/ and include the crash backtrace, preprocessed source, and associated run script.
clang: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
clang: error: clang frontend command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
Apple LLVM version 4.2 (clang-425.0.28) (based on LLVM 3.2svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.2
Thread model: posix
clang: note: diagnostic msg: PLEASE submit a bug report to http://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/ and include the crash backtrace, preprocessed source, and associated run script.
clang: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
clang: note: diagnostic msg: Error generating preprocessed source(s).
make: *** [basedll_any.o] Error 254
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
clang: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
clang: note: diagnostic msg: Error generating preprocessed source(s).
make: *** [basedll_appbase.o] Error 254

Do not report this issue to Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core!


Error: You are using macOS 10.7.
We (and Apple) do not provide support for this old version.
You may encounter build failures or other breakages.
Please create pull-requests instead of filing issues.

Error: You are using macOS 10.7.
We (and Apple) do not provide support for this old version.
You may encounter build failures or other breakages.
Please create pull-requests instead of filing issues.
```

---

Ironically, entering 'brew install wxpython' on the same MacBook early 2007 with MacOS X 10.6.8 [on a separate Partition] - the installation was successful, and all works well.

Question: Is it possible to install wxpython under MacOS X 10.7.X?, and - if so, how?

Thank you for any information or assistance.

Comment: Well, it appears that the Stackflow Post of 'How do I install wxPython on Mac OS X?', by David Matuszek and a Solution provided answered by 'x - y', has allowed me to install wxPython on my MacBook.

Comment: 'x - y' provided the http://downloads.sourceforge.net/wxpython/wxPython2.9-osx-2.9.4.0-cocoa-py2.7.dmg Link.

A simple 'Hallo Welt' (Hello World) Program confirmed that 'import wx', etc. works.

Thank you 'x - y' and Sourceoverflow.